# Google Cloud Storage : how many can create ACL

Tags: google-cloud-storage, acl

In the google document, it says:

> "The maximum number of ACL entries you can create for a bucket or object is 100"

does that mean I can create just 100 Regardless of objects or buckets? or I can create 100 each objects and bucket?

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All objects and all buckets have an ACL list. Any ACL list may have up to 100 entries, but no more. So a bucket can have 100 entries in its ACL, and an object in that bucket may also have 100 entries in that object's ACL.

Note: it is generally not recommended to place large numbers of ACL entries in an object or bucket's ACL list. Instead, consider one of these alternatives, which both have the advantage of not needing to modify the bucket or object when adding or removing users and groups:

1. Add the user or groups you need to your project's OWNER, EDITOR, and VIEWER roles, and use those roles in your bucket and object ACLs.
2. Add the user or groups you need to a google group and then add that google group to your bucket and object ACLs.